# Eclipse: Error installing m2e connector for liferay-maven-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

When importing a maven project into Eclipse (after installing the maven plugin) I get the following errors:

```
UNKNOWN HOST: http://releases.liferay.com/tools/ide/latest/stable/compositeContent.xml
softlayer-ams.dl.sourceforge.net

Error installing m2e connector for liferay-maven-plugin contacting repository         http://releases.liferay.com/tools/ide/latest/stable/
```

Should I install Liferay IDE? liferay - http://releases.liferay.com/tools/ide/latest/milestone/

Any ideas?

I installed liferay plugin now I get

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
m2e connector for jaxb2 3.0.0.20130330-0126
m2e connector for mavenarchiver pom properties  0.16.0.201401211452
m2e-liferay - Maven Integration for Liferay IDE 2.0.1.201401270944-ga2
```

I was able to import the project but now it says:

```
  The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library jnlp-1.6.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Uninstall Eclipse. Then re-install with the needed plugins.

Comment: Which ones were the needed plugins?

Comment: So in the project you import there is a pom file. The pom file defines all the dependencies you need (plugins). For some reason after I uninstalled Eclipse, re-checked out the code, clean+build, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem installing "Maven Integration for WTP"

For Eclipse Kepler you can find it here:

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler

**m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP** (version 1.0.1)

It's inside "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi..."

This package includes "**m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse**" and my problem before was I used to install only this one